# Github: Pull some commits from fork into original project

Tags: git, github, merge, fork, git-branch

I, `user1`, have a project at github. Another `user2` created a fork and made three commits: `A` `B` and `C`.

I want to merge only commits `A` and `B` back into my project.

How to do it, that I could keep the history in github's network graph?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a remote reference to the fork, create a branch on B, and merge that branch (in, for instance, `master`):

```
git remote add fork /url/of/fork
git fetch --all
git branch tmp fork/B
git checkout master
git merge tmp
```

I find the merge cleaner than [using `git cherry-pick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309).

The [OP Michał Sałaban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465366/micha%C5%82-sa%C5%82aban) preferred (in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586946/github-pull-some-commits-from-fork-into-original-project#comment38090916_24587031)) create the branch with:

```
git checkout B 
git branch tmp
```

Comment: Actually it was:
`git remote add fork /url/of/fork`
`git fetch --all`
`git checkout B`
`git branch tmp`
`git checkout master`
`git merge tmp`

Comment: @MichałSałaban good points. I have included them in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use github pull request.

GIthub pull request help: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

How?

simple:

open a new branch from your current state

```
git checkout "COMMIT_B_ID"
```

**this will result in detached HEAD**

now create a new named branch

```
git checkout "MY_B_BRANCH"
git push origin MY_B_BRANCH
```

now github contains new branch with your changes.
Go to github and open a pull reauest to merge the new branch with the master

This way (Pull requsest) you can see and verfiy that this is exactly what needs to be commited.

Godd Luck.